# How to increase my vocal range?

Tags: vocal-range

When I was about 4 years old, my vocal range was high. But now (15 years old), my vocal range has became too low.

My mother tells that if I sing low octaves, my vocal range will increase. How much effective is that practice ? And please suggest some other practices to increase the vocal range.

Comment: Be glad you don't have the same range as when you were four... :)

Comment: You'll find lots of advice on the internet on how to increase your vocal range, some methods more effective than others. Honestly though, the best advice you could get is to have proper singing lessons to figure out what will work for you - something that may work well for one person may have no effect on another.